# Flutter does not recognize android device

Tags: android, linux, flutter

I have an android phone and I am trying to install a flutter application on this phone. For some reason that I am unaware of, both Flutter and IDE (IntelliJ or Android Studio) do not recognize the connected device. I've done all the basic steps and try another solutions that I found such as:

```
JAVA_HOME is configured as well, ANDROID_HOME
Configure android-sdk on the flutter (flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk)
```

Other relevant stuff:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.3-pre.7, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

flutter devices
2 connected devices:

Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130
Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
**I expected my android device here**

cat /etc/linuxmint/info 
RELEASE=19.3
CODENAME=tricia
EDITION="Cinnamon"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tricia_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tricia_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=https://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon
```

IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

**What I'm doing wrong? I thank you for your help!**

Answer (score 2):

Check that:

1. You have the USB driver for device installed.
2. You have enabled **USB Debugging** in phone's developer settings.

Comment: First, thanks you for help. I forgot to say, so yes, I have enabled developer mode on my phone and I have debugging enabled, I think that's not the problem, I tested it on other computers